# How to find intersection points on edge

Tags: c#, intersection

Hi I am writing small script that analyze point data - everything is almost done but I stuck on finding the intersection between two lines (edge) with a given length between those points. Image below illustrates the problem better:

[image]

Edit: its only two-dimensional problem & distance between DB & BE should be equal

Comment: there are inifinit number of points satisfying this conditions. you have to select and length of one point

Comment: Without further restrictions, there are many ways to get D and E with a fixed distance DE. Do you want to be BD = BE? Or maybe BA/BD = BC/BE?

Comment: @MOehm its only two-dimensional problem & distance between DB & BE should be equal

Comment: [Check this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sH5cs.png). Red and Green segment have same length as `DE` segment. Can you define better criteria of where `D` and `E` points located? *distance between DB & BE should be equal* is not really meaningful.

Comment: @Sinatr you are joking right? DB & BE should be equal - there is only ONE B point specified... also other points like A & C... ehhh i read couple of times your comment i now i get your point - maybe my criteria was unclear - distance between points D & B and distance between B & E should be equal

Comment: @user3688059, so `DB = BE`. Not some *distance between*. Good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you want the distance `DE` to be a given `L`. Your points `{D}` and `{E}` are

```
{D} = {B} + x * {a}
{E} = {B} + x * {c}
```

where `{a}` is the normalised vector `BA` and `{c}` is the normalised vector `BC`. (These vectors have to be of the same length so that the same factor `x` can be used for both. Normalisation is the easiest way to enforce this.)

Now you have the equation:

```
L = |{D} - {E}|
  = |x*{a} - x*{c}|
```

Broken down to the vector components:

```
L = sqrt((x*ax - x*cx)² + (x*ay - x*cy)²)
  = x * sqrt((ax - cx)² + (ay - cy)²)
```

Solve for `x`:

```
x = L / sqrt((ax - cx)² + (ay - cy)²)
```

and use the found `x` in the first equations above.

Comment: Finally had time to implement this - well, it works - so big thanks but D E points  are not created on AB BC segments. Am I doing something wrong or they can be created like that?

Comment: Do you mean that the points lie on the line that passes through A and B, but not in the segment? Yes, that can happen when the segments are not very long or if the angle between them is acute. The point lies outside `AB` when `x > |AB|`.